# PowerShell Unexpected Token Error during transliteration

Tags: powershell

I want to transliterate filenames from Cyrillic to Latin using the following script:

```
Get-ChildItem -Attributes !directory+!system | Where-Object {
    $_.BaseName -match '[абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя]'
} | Rename-Item -NewName {
    '{0}{1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace 'ний', 'ny' -replace 'сий', 'sy' -replace 'тий', 'ty' -replace 'жд', 'zd' -replace 'ай', 'ay' -replace 'ей', 'ey' -replace 'ёй', 'ey' -replace 'ий', 'iy' -replace 'ия', 'ia' -replace 'ой', 'oy' -replace 'уй', 'uy' -replace 'ый', 'uy' -replace 'эй', 'ey' -replace 'ья', 'ia' -replace 'ье', 'ye' -replace 'ьё', 'ye' -replace 'ьа', 'ia' -replace 'ьи', 'yi' -replace 'ьо', 'yo' -replace 'ьу', 'yu' -replace 'ьы', 'yy' -replace 'ьэ', 'ye' -replace 'ью', 'yu' -replace 'кс', 'x'  -replace 'юй', 'yuy' -replace 'яй', 'yay' -replace 'лю', 'liu' -replace 'ж', 'zh' -replace 'х', 'kh' -replace 'ц', 'ts' -replace 'ч', 'ch' -replace 'ш', 'sh' -replace 'я', 'ya' -replace 'ю', 'yu' -replace 'щ', 'shch' -replace 'ъ', ''   -replace 'ь', ''   -replace 'а', 'a'  -replace 'б', 'b'  -replace 'в', 'v'  -replace 'г', 'g'  -replace 'д', 'd'  -replace 'е', 'e'  -replace 'ё', 'e'  -replace 'з', 'z'  -replace 'и', 'i'  -replace 'й', 'y'  -replace 'к', 'k'  -replace 'л', 'l'  -replace 'м', 'm'  -replace 'н', 'n'  -replace 'о', 'o'  -replace 'п', 'p'  -replace 'р', 'r'  -replace 'с', 's'  -replace 'т', 't'  -replace 'у', 'u'  -replace 'ф', 'f'  -replace 'ы', 'y'  -replace 'э', 'e'), $_.Extension
}
```

but it errors out with `PowerShell Unexpected Token '<bunch of gibberish>' in expression or statement`. How could I go about fixing this?

Comment: The code snippet runs smoothly using files with base name randomly permuted string `'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'` (repeatedly). Maybe posting _full error message_ **and** filename of the 1st _unrenamed_ file could show more?

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/aPzolrF.png)'s a screenshot of the error(s). The window pops up and instantly disappears even if I put a Pause at the end, so I can't copy-paste it.

Comment: Oh and an example file name could be `абв.txt`. The script errors out, and name remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Powershell can't recognize encoding UTF-8 **without** [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark):

```
D:\PShell\SU\1538755_NoBom.ps1
```

> ```
> At D:\PShell\SU\1538755_NoBom.ps1:2 char:41
> + ... Đ°Đ±Đ˛ĐłĐ´ĐµŃ‘Đ¶Đ·Đ¸ĐąĐşĐ»ĐĽĐ˝ĐľĐżŃ€ŃŃ‚ŃƒŃ„Ń…Ń†Ń‡ŃˆŃ‰ŃŠŃ‹ŃŚŃŤŃŽŃŹ' |
> +                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Unexpected token 'Đ¶Đ·Đ¸ĐąĐşĐ»ĐĽĐ˝ĐľĐżŃ€ŃŃ‚ŃƒŃ„Ń…Ń†Ń‡ŃˆŃ‰ŃŠŃ‹ŃŚŃŤŃŽŃŹ'' in expression
> or statement.
> …
> ```

**Solution**: Open the file in Notepad++, change encoding to `UTF-8-BOM` and save:

[image: encoding N++]

Of course, there is a programmatic way to do that:

```
Get-Content -Path .\SU\1538755_NoBom.ps1 -Encoding UTF8 | 
  Set-Content -Path .\SU\1538755_Bom.ps1 -Encoding UTF8
```

**Edit**. The issue appears only in *Windows Powershell* (`powershell.exe`) because it's a  [Microsoft product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8):

> … Microsoft compilers and *interpreters*, and many pieces of software
>   on Microsoft Windows such as Notepad *treat the BOM as a **required**
>   magic number* rather than use heuristics. These tools add a BOM when
>   saving text as UTF-8, and cannot interpret UTF-8 unless the BOM is
>   present or the file contains only ASCII…

Other Powershell versions:

- [Powershell 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#PowerShell_7) (`pwsh.exe`) treats UTF-8 encoded files well (your script runs smoothly regardless of a BOM presence).
- Unfortunately, I can't check such behaviour of *Powershell Core 6.x (`pwsh.exe`)*…

Comment: That worked! Interesting. Isn't utf-8 w/ BOM generally discouraged? Why would Powershell not work without it? Is there really no other way around it?